# What is windows equivalent to linux's /dev/video0?

Tags: java, linux, windows, webcam

I was wondering if anyone knows how to find webcam in windows like you do in linux - /dev/video0. I need this for java so this could start webcam `frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("path_to_webcam");`

Comment: Check out [this](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/) API. It'll do all you need I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to know if you got It fixed
I found something similar to that using ffmpeg in windows, as in linux we use just the "/dev/video0", but in windows we have to specify the name of the video interface

and If you want to have the name of you device you have this is how

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

and for my example, I got a long answer as It's like dumping all the devices to get the right one,

```
...
 [dshow @ 03e746c0] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 03e746c0]  "Integrated Camera"
...
```

In the documentation they mention something called DirectShow

here's the link if you want to get documented about that

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow